# Function does not return true even if it goes through

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, async-await

I can't seem to make this work but I want to return true every-time the function executes successfully, which in this case is "Changing the password".

```
async function ChangePassword(data) {
  const auth = getAuth();
  let res = false;
  const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
    auth.currentUser.email,
    data.oldPassword
  );
  reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential)
    .then(() => {
      updatePassword(auth.currentUser, data.password)
        .then(() => {
          toast.success("Password changed successfully");
          res = true;
          console.log("res ",res);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          toast.error(error.message);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      toast.error(error.message);
    });
  return res;
}
```

The res variable when called by other functions always results in `false` even though I see the toast message "Password changed successfully".

```
async function changePassword() {
    if (password === "" || confirmPassword === "" || oldPassword === "") {
      toast.error("Please fill all the fields");
    } else if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      toast.error("Passwords do not match");
    } else {
      let data = { oldPassword, password };
      await ChangePassword(data).then((res) => {
        if (res === true) {
          setChangePasswordModal(false);
          setOpen(false);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

The if condition in above code never executes because `res` is always false. I know it has something to do with async await but can't figure out how to make it work

Comment: Oh god. Mixing `Promise` with synchronous code + `async` is going to setup you up for a bad time.

Comment: Either use `Promise.then` and alike, or `async` but please NOT both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function ChangePassword(data) {
  const auth = getAuth();
  let res = false;
  const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
    auth.currentUser.email,
    data.oldPassword
  );
  reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential)
    .then(() => {
      updatePassword(auth.currentUser, data.password)
        .then(() => {
          toast.success("Password changed successfully");
          res = true;
          console.log("res ",res);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          toast.error(error.message);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      toast.error(error.message);
    });
  return res;
}
```

Has many logical errors in it.

First you should decide whether you're going to use `async` and its feature `await` or classical Promise `.then`able -style. Please do not use both, it will only confuse you and the reader.

Let's ditch the async (since you don't even use `await`), and `Promise`s are chainable, you do not (and MUST not) nest `.then` blocks, use this instead:

```
function ChangePassword(data) {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(auth.currentUser.email, data.oldPassword);

  return reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential)
  .then(() => {
      return updatePassword(auth.currentUser, data.password)
  })
  .then(() => {
      toast.success("Password changed successfully");

      return true;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      toast.error(error.message);

      return false;
  })
}
```

The key here is that `ChangePassword` *itself* returns a Promise.*

The caller is then responsible to call it with `.then` or use `async` in combination with `await`:

```
ChangePassword({/* data */}).then((result) => {
    console.log("ChangePassword done", result)
})
```

The same code looks a lot cleaner if you use `async`:

```
async function ChangePassword(data) {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(auth.currentUser.email, data.oldPassword);

  try {
    await reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential);
    await updatePassword(auth.currentUser, data.password);
    toast.success("Password changed successfully");

    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error(error.message);

    return false;
  }
}
```

(If you were wondering how that would look like).

*a function tagged as `async` **ALWAYS** returns a promise, by the way.

Comment: This makes it easier to understand. Thank you!

Comment: @SahilN You're welcome. I know, `Promise`s can be confusing at first. Please remember to not mix `async` with `.then` and friends. The key (of understanding Promises) is that you chain them together with `.then` blocks because you're relying on a value that is not (yet) available. It's like this: each part of the "chain" is executed as soon as the value is known. When that is, is not known until runtime (you run the code). You can return another Promise from a `.then()` block, so you don't have to nest `.then()` blocks.